# Cant install Mariadb on Debian 11

Tags: debian, mariadb

Im trying to install it on Debian 11

```
curl -LsS https://r.mariadb.com/downloads/mariadb_repo_setup | sudo bash -s -- --os-type=debian --os-version=11 --mariadb-server-version="mariadb-10.5"
# [info] Skipping OS detection and using OS type 'debian' and version '11' as given on the command line
# [info] Checking for script prerequisites.
# [warning] Found existing file at /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.list. Moving to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.list.old_2
# [error] Problem encountered while trying to verify the MariaDB Server version:
          curl: (28) Failed to connect to dlm.mariadb.com port 443: Connection timed out
#         The latest MariaDB Server versions are:
#
#
#         More information on MariaDB releases is available at:
#             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes/
```

I have seen this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73988085/mariadb-version-10-5-9-unable-to-install

I also have tried with "10.5.10" version and get the same error.
I have check the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.list file and it is empty.

Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Comment: The error message *"failed to connect to dlm.mariadb.com port 443: Connection timed out"*  suggests either a problem on that mirror site OR a firewall/connectivity  issue from your end.

Comment: I have test curl with some url and its OK. I also have proxy configurated on "enviroment" file. I dont understand what the problem could be.

Comment: *"I also have proxy configured on "environment" file"*  - that environment probably doesn't sourced or honoured properly in the `curl script | sudo` construct.  I'd download and save that script, elevate your privileges with `sudo -i` , check that your proxy environment has loaded and then execute the saved setup script.

Comment: @HBruijn How can i do that ? save the script to a file .sh ? sorry, im not a linux expert

Comment: `curl -LsS https://r.mariadb.com/downloads/mariadb_repo_setup > /path/tho/filename`  ; then make the script executable  `chmod +x /path/tho/filename`  ; then become root `sudo -i`  and check that your environment is correctly configured to use the proxy server (i..e the http_proxy HTTP_PROXY resp https versions are populated ) ; then execute that script `/path/tho/filename  [options]`

Comment: @HBruijn I have donwloaded script to file called "scr": I execute  sudo sh ./scr.sh  -s -- --os-type=debian --os-version=11 --mariadb-server-version="mariadb-10.5"
and i got ./scr.sh: 159: Syntax error: "(" unexpected - the 159 line > key_ids=( 0x8167EE24 0xE3C94F49 0xcbcb082a1bb943db 0xf1656f24c74cd1d8 0x135659e928c12247 )